# Porting nested for loop over the same list to a Java Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In an effort to learn Java, I'm working on a solution to the 
[Project Euler's problem 23](https://projecteuler.net/problem=23) 
where I need to find the sum of all the positive integers which cannot be
written as the sum of two abundant numbers. My solution uses Java 8 streams. I
will not spoil it by posting the actual answer here, but I will discuss my
strategy to get to the solution.

First, I create a list of abundant numbers using an IntStream:

```
List<Integer> abundants = IntStream.range(1, EULER23_MAX)
        .filter(i -> Util.sumOfDivisors(i) > i)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then, based on the list, I create a set of sums of 2 abundants numbers lower
than the max:

```
private Set<Integer> calcSumsOfTwoAbundants(List<Integer> abundants) {
    Set<Integer> iset = new HashSet<>();
    Integer[] arr = abundants.toArray(new Integer[abundants.size()]);

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 2; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < arr.length - 1; j++) {
            int sum = arr[i] + arr[j];
            if (sum <= EULER23_MAX) {
                iset.add(sum);
            }
        }
    }

    return iset;
}
```

Lastly, I generate another stream that filters out all numbers lower than the
max that are present in the set of sums of two abundants, and I sum that to get
to the result.

```
result = IntStream.range(1, EULER23_MAX)
        .filter(x -> !sumsOfTwoAbundants.contains(x))
        .sum();
```

*My questions is this:* How can I encode the logic in `calcSumsOfTwoAbundants` to
use a streams fluent syntax instead of the nested `for` loops? I have tried a
couple of different things, but I keep getting to the "stream has already been
closed" error message or to the entirely wrong result. I also understand the
the nested `for` loops are perhaps faster than using streams, but this is
purely an intellectual exercise ... this is what I have right now:

```
// wrong results
private Set<Integer> calcSumsOfTwoAbundantsAlt(List<Integer> abundants) {
    return abundants.stream()
            .filter(i -> abundants.stream()
                    .anyMatch(j -> (i + j) <= EULER23_MAX))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Comment: What drives the end condition of the outer loop, and the start of the inner one, is not the values of the `abundant` list, but the actual index/offset of the current item. Therefore, I suggest you try to build a stream implementation out of the iteration indexes (`IntStream.range(0, abundant.size()`), and not out of `abundant.stream()`. Anyway you end up doing it, keeping the index at hand is crucrial to you getting the good result.

Comment: Arent you leaving the last array member out with the condition?

Comment: @NiVeR No, because the value of EULER23_MAX accounts for that off-by-one situation ... but that is not obvious in the code I provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most direct equivalent would be replacing each for loop with `IntStream.range` and nesting them with `flatMap`:

```
Set<Integer> iset = IntStream.range(0, arr.length - 2)
        .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(i, arr.length - 1)
                .map(j -> arr[i] + arr[j]).filter(s -> s <= EULER23_MAX))
        .boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```